# Make OR condition for generic

Tags: typescript

Consider type

```
type Smth<T, U> = ...
```

Now I want to check if `T` is `string` OR `U` is primitive.

---

I can check conditions separately

```
type AreSame<T, U, Y, N> = (<X>() => X extends T ? 1 : 2) extends (<X>() => X extends U ? 1 : 2) ? Y : N
type IfAny<T, Y, N> = 0 extends (1 & T) ? Y : N
type IfPrimitive<T, Y, N> = T extends string | number | boolean | symbol | bigint | null | undefined ? IfAny<T, N, Y> : N

type Smth1<T, U> = AreSame<T, string, true, false>
type Smth2<T, U> = IfPrimitive<U, true, false>
```

but how to join them via `or`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just put second condition into falsy branch of the first:

```
type AreSame<T, U, Y, N> = (<X>() => X extends T ? 1 : 2) extends (<X>() => X extends U ? 1 : 2) ? Y : N
type IfAny<T, Y, N> = 0 extends (1 & T) ? Y : N
type IfPrimitive<T, Y, N> = T extends string | number | boolean | symbol | bigint | null | undefined ? IfAny<T, N, Y> : N

type Smth<T, U> = AreSame<T, string, true, IfPrimitive<U, true, false>>
```